# How to remove a remote notification from notification center using UserNotifications framework

Tags: usernotifications

I have seen several threads on this here and elsewhere but none seem to be using the new `UserNotifications` framework for iOS 10

There is an instance method `getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler:)` that is called on `UNUserNotificationCenter` singleton function `current()`

The `completionHandler:` takes an array of delivered notifications that could then be removed inside the block using `removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers:)`

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications { notifications in 
    // UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [String])
}
```

My challenge is how to identify a specific notification from all delivered notifications and then remove it?

This is what I am doing right now to see if there is a remote notification delivered with the id I had sent from the server with the payload key `ID`. This doesn't remove the notification in question, obviously because the first function returns nil although the notification is visible in the notification center.

```
func isThereANotificationForID(_ ID: Int) -> UNNotification? {    
    var foundNotification: UNNotification?

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            for notification in notifications {
                if notification.request.content.userInfo["id"] as! Int == ID {
                    foundNotification = notification
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return foundNotification
}

func removeNotification(_ notification: UNNotification) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [notification.request.identifier])
}

// Find the notification and remove it
if let deliveredNotification = isThereANotificationForID(ID) {
    removeNotification(deliveredNotification)
}
```

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: @Ahmed Khedr if you got a solution. please post here

Answer (score 3):

Note that this answer is using **Swift 5** and tested on iOS 13.

We can extend `UNUserNotificationCenter` to remove the notification(s) of our choice. Personally, I group them by thread and remove them that way, but this extension also includes a way to remove by dictionary pair.

```swift
extension UNUserNotificationCenter {
    func decreaseBadgeCount(by notificationsRemoved: Int? = nil) {
        let notificationsRemoved = notificationsRemoved ?? 1
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber -= notificationsRemoved
        }
    }

    func removeNotifications(_ notifications: [UNNotification], decreaseBadgeCount: Bool = false) {
        let identifiers = notifications.map { $0.request.identifier }
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: identifiers)
        if decreaseBadgeCount {
            self.decreaseBadgeCount(by: notifications.count)
        }
    }

    func removeNotifications<T: Comparable>(whereKey key: AnyHashable, hasValue value: T, decreaseBadgeCount: Bool = false) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications { notifications in
            let notificationsToRemove = notifications.filter {
                guard let userInfoValue = $0.request.content.userInfo[key] as? T else { return false }
                return userInfoValue == value
            }
            self.removeNotifications(notificationsToRemove, decreaseBadgeCount: decreaseBadgeCount)
        }
    }

    func removeNotifications(withThreadIdentifier threadIdentifier: String, decreaseBadgeCount: Bool = false) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications { notifications in
            let notificationsToRemove = notifications.filter { $0.request.content.threadIdentifier == threadIdentifier }
            self.removeNotifications(notificationsToRemove, decreaseBadgeCount: decreaseBadgeCount)
        }
    }

    func removeNotification(_ notification: UNNotification, decreaseBadgeCount: Bool = false) {
        removeNotifications([notification], decreaseBadgeCount: decreaseBadgeCount)
    }
}
```

With this extension in place, you can call, for example,

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeNotifications(whereKey: "id", hasValue: 123)
```

If you also want to decrease the badge number on the app icon, you can set `decreaseBadgeCount: true`, or alternately call `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().decreaseBadgeCount`.

Answer (score 0):

Previosly `removeDeliveredNotifications` is not work properly. It seems like Apple was fixed issue because it will work for me by using the single line of code.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: aryIdentifier)
```

I have tried 5-6 hours in the simulator to clear local notification but no luck. When I will run code in the actual device it will like the charm.

**NOTE: Please test into real device, Above method are not working in simulator.**